# How to take high-quality screenshot with UIGraphicsImageRenderer programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgcontext, uigraphicsimagerenderer

**PROBLEM**: After I take screenshot the image is blurry when check by zooming. The text inside image seems to be blurred when zoomed.

I know this question have been raised many a times but none of them have desired solution. I already checked quite a few post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942820/how-to-capture-high-resolution-image-from-uiview?noredirect=1#comment115569779_61942820)

All the solution been shared so far on this forum are repeated or same in any other way but none of them has a solution for the problem.

Here is what I am doing:

```
extension UIView {

  func asImage() -> UIImage? {
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.opaque = self.isOpaque
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds,format: format)
    return renderer.image(actions: { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    })
}

//The other option using UIGraphicsEndImageContext

func asImage() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

The above function will convert UIView into and image but the image quality returned is not up-to the mark.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your code?  You take a screenshot?  How?  And you just want to resize it?  Where is the original image?

Comment: Please check my updated questions. I am trying to take screenshot or you can say convert UIView into an image. But the image returned is not in good quality.

Comment: That's not the source of your problem.

Comment: I now know what you are trying to do.  No.  You only get the size of the view for the screenshot.  If you resize it into a bigger size, of course, a resulting picture will become blurry.

Comment: No even if I don't resize it, without resizing it with actual bounds it comes as blurry. Thats the problem I have. I mean when you see normally it looks perfect, but when you zoom it the pixels are not enough to give sharp visualisation.

Comment: If you say so...  Try setting `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext.interpolationQuality` to `high`.

Comment: There is no visible change using it. I compared before and after image but couldn't find much difference. But I appreciate your response for same.
 

Comment: @ParvezBelim it is actually the opposite to avoid blur. Try without interpolation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692616/2303865 If you would like to increase the resolution of your image you need to create a larger image context and draw/render into it.

Comment: @LeoDabus thankyou for your comment, I tried to make .none but it doesn't work. FYI I am not resizing, I am creating a complete new image from base. And as far as UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext.interpolationQuality concerned, it tells the type of quality to use from raw file while drawing the image. So I think keeping it high is the only way. Although it also not able to get me the desired result.

Comment: Hi! I see you mentioned my Q&A. So it seems we are dealing with the same problem -> building editor for users. I’m aware of fact that my question isn’t the best. I was thinking about different approach. What if we made everything in the desired bigger size and use CGAffineTransform, to scale down everything? Then we could make a screenshot in HD.

Comment: @OndřejKorol Thankyou for your comment so far. We can use CGAffineTransform to scale the content and take screenshot, however it doesn't give much effects on the text. Changing the bounds and frame will not help because ultimately we have to apply transform which user has used in scale, rotate and drag while editing image.

Answer (score 3):

You won't get your desired results by doing a `UIView` "image capture."

When you zoom a `UIScrollView` it does **not** perform a *vector* scaling... it performs a *rasterized* scaling.

You can easily confirm this by using a `UILabel` as the `viewForZooming`. Here is a label with 30-point system font...

at `1x` zoom:

[image]

at `10x` zoom:

[image]

Code for that example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let zoomLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [zoomLabel, scrollView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        scrollView.addSubview(zoomLabel)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            zoomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            zoomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            zoomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            zoomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        zoomLabel.textColor = .red
        zoomLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        zoomLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30.0, weight: .regular)
        zoomLabel.text = "Sample Text"
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return zoomLabel
    }

}
```

When you "capture the view content" as a `UIImage`, you get a bitmap that is the size of the view *in points* x the screen scale.

So, on an iPhone 8, for example, with `@2x` screen scale, at `300 x 200` view will be "captured" as a `UIImage` with `600 x 400` pixels.

Whether you zoom the view itself, or a bitmap-capture of the view, you'll get the same result -- blurry edges when zoomed.

Your comments include: *"... while editing image ..."* -- this is a common issue, where we want to allow the user to add text (labels), Bezier Path shapes, addition images, etc. What the user sees on the screen, for example, may be an original image of `3000 x 2000` pixels, displayed at `300 x 200` points. Adding a 30-point label might look good *on the screen*, but then grabbing that as a `UIImage` (either for zooming or for saving to disk), ends up as a `600 x 400` pixel image which, of course, will not look good at a larger size.

Frequently, the approach to resolve this is along these lines:

Allow the user to edit at screen dimensions, e.g.

- show a `3000 x 2000` pixel image scaled down in a `300 x 200` view
- add a Bezier Path, oval-in-rect (20, 20, 200, 200)
- add a 30-point label at origin `(32, 32)`

Then, when "capturing" that for output / zooming

- take the *original* `3000 x 2000` pixel image
- add a Bezier Path, oval-in-rect (20 * 10, 20 * 10, 200 * 10, 200 * 10)
- add a (30 * 10)-point label at origin `(32 * 10, 32 * 10)`

Another option is to do the on-screen editing ***scaled-down***.

So, you might use a `300 x 200` image view, with your `3000 x 2000` pixel image (scale to fit). When the user says "I want to add an oval Bezier Path in rect `(20, 20, 200, 200)`, your code would draw that oval at rect `(20 * 10, 20 * 10, 200 * 10, 200 * 10)` *on the image itself* and then refresh the `.image` property of the image view.

Here's a little more detailed example to help make things clear:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let topView: UIView = UIView()
    let topLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    let botView: UIView = UIView()
    let botLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    let topScrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let botScrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()

    let topStatLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let botStatLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [topView, topLabel, botView, botLabel, topScrollView, botScrollView, topStatLabel, botStatLabel].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        topView.addSubview(topLabel)
        botView.addSubview(botLabel)

        topScrollView.addSubview(topView)
        botScrollView.addSubview(botView)

        view.addSubview(topStatLabel)
        view.addSubview(botStatLabel)
        
        view.addSubview(topScrollView)
        view.addSubview(botScrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            topStatLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            topStatLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.leadingAnchor),

            topScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topStatLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            topScrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            topScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            topScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            botScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            botScrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            botScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            botScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            botStatLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            botStatLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            
            topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            botView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0 * 10.0),
            botView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0 * 10.0),
            
            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            botLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0 * 10.0),
            botLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0 * 10.0),
            
            topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

            botView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            botView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            botView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            botView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: botScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        topLabel.textColor = .red
        topLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        topLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30.0, weight: .regular)
        topLabel.text = "Sample Text"
        
        botLabel.textColor = .red
        botLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        botLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30.0 * 10.0, weight: .regular)
        botLabel.text = "Sample Text"
        
        topScrollView.delegate = self
        topScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        topScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10
        
        botScrollView.delegate = self
        botScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
        botScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
        
        topScrollView.zoomScale = topScrollView.minimumZoomScale
        botScrollView.zoomScale = botScrollView.minimumZoomScale

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        topScrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        botScrollView.backgroundColor = .white

        topStatLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
        topStatLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        botStatLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
        botStatLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updateStatLabels()
    }
    
    func updateStatLabels() -> Void {
        var sTop = ""
        sTop += "Label Point Size: \(topLabel.font.pointSize)"
        sTop += "\n"
        sTop += "Label Frame: \(topLabel.frame)"
        sTop += "\n"
        sTop += "View Size: \(topView.bounds.size)"
        sTop += "\n"
        sTop += "Zoom Scale: \(String(format: "%0.1f", topScrollView.zoomScale))"
        
        var sBot = ""
        sBot += "Zoom Scale: \(String(format: "%0.1f", botScrollView.zoomScale))"
        sBot += "\n"
        sBot += "View Size: \(botView.bounds.size)"
        sBot += "\n"
        sBot += "Label Frame: \(botLabel.frame)"
        sBot += "\n"
        sBot += "Label Point Size: \(botLabel.font.pointSize)"
        
        topStatLabel.text = sTop
        botStatLabel.text = sBot
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        if scrollView == topScrollView {
            return topView
        }
        return botView
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        
        if Int(topScrollView.zoomScale) == Int(topScrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
            topScrollView.zoomScale = topScrollView.minimumZoomScale
        } else {
            topScrollView.zoomScale += 1
        }
        topScrollView.contentOffset = .zero

        // comparing floating point directly will fail, so round the values
        if round(botScrollView.zoomScale * 10) == round(botScrollView.maximumZoomScale * 10) {
            botScrollView.zoomScale = botScrollView.minimumZoomScale
        } else {
            botScrollView.zoomScale += 0.1
        }

        botScrollView.contentOffset = .zero

        updateStatLabels()
    }
    
}
```

The top scroll view has a `300 x 200` view with a 30-point label, allowing zoomScale from `1 to 10`.

The bottom scroll view has a `3000 x 2000` view with a 300-point label, allowing zoomScale from `0.1 to 1.0`.

Each time you tap the screen, the scrollViews increase zoomScale by 1 and 0.1 respectively.

And it looks like this at min-scale:

[image]

at 5 and 0.5 scale:

[image]

and at 10 and 1.0 scale:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the descriptive answer. It means a lot. But in my app, I am working on image editor, and I am not suppose to show zoomed canvas to user, I only have fix bounds which is of screen bound size. And user will be able to add content inside that bound only. So the only option I have is to create a copy of existing editor view and recreate the content according to desired image size ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Reported this solution is not longer useful from iOS17 and above.

I am using this code in one of my apps and seems to work fine. Don't know if its quality is enough for you.

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {

    var screenShot: UIImage?  {

        if let layer = keyWindow?.layer {
            let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
            if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                layer.render(in: context)
                let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                return screenshot
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you use the size of a phone screen. So I’d guess that when you export this screenshot and zoom it, you’d get blurry image.

Comment: Yes I am using the size of the screen because I render the image in the same screen, but you can fit the scale to the size you want. I did not see the blurry effect but I will check it.

Comment: ```UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions``` Does not work anymore on iOS17

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I will add this note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension to create an image from the view UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns a reference to the current graphics context. It will not create one. It is important to remember this, because if you look at it this way, you will find that it does not need the size parameter, because the current context is just the size used when creating the graphics context.

```
extension UIView {
   func toImage() -> UIImage? {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

      drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      return image
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already as you can see in my question. The problem is it takes screen shot of visible area, so when you zoom it, the pixel gets blurred for text and images. Which is not acceptable.